# Why is Firestore giving me two timestamps with 2 different timezones?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Does this have something to do with daylight saving time since March 7th is winter time whereas June 10th is summer?

Today is 27th March and daylight saving time doesn't come into effect until tomorrow here in Western Europe.

Here's a screenshot from the Firestore document.

[image]

Comment: One thing to note - I'm *assuming* that this is a screenshot from the Firestore console, but it would be really helpful if you'd say that explicitly in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't two different time zones - it's two different *UTC offsets* that are observed in *one* time zone.

A Firestore timestamp is just an instant in time. What you're seeing are two instants in time, converted into your local time zone - at which point the one in June has an offset of UTC+2, and the one in March has an offset of UTC+1.